# How to filter array using lodash

Tags: javascript, vue.js, lodash

I am trying to sort an array of cars using the Lodash library. I want to look for a specific car. This is my code:

```
const selectedcar= ref('');


const data_car = computed(() => {
    let filter = {};
    if (selectedcar.value === '') {
        filter = {};
        return props.data;
    } else {
        filter = { componentDesc: selectedcar.value }
        return _.filter(props.data, filter);
    }
})
```

```
    const selectedyear = ref('');
const selectedcar = ref('');

const data_filt = computed(() => {
    let filter = {};
        if (selectedyear.value === '') {
            filter = { any : "2021"}
        } else {
            filter = { any: selectedyear.value }
        }
        if (selectedcar .value !== '') {
            filter.car= selectedcar .value
        }

        return _.filter(props.data, filter);
})
```

This does not work and does not give an error, nothing follows.

I have tried to restart the database, to redo everything from 0 but nothing worked.

Comment: Please [edit] to include a [mcve]. We don't know what `props.data` contains, nor what `selectedcar.value` would be.

Comment: import { defineProps } from 'vue';
import _ from 'lodash';
import { ref } from 'vue';
import { computed } from '@vue/reactivity';

these are the imports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is lodash a hard requirement? With ES6 you can use the inbuilt .filter method.

```
const filtered = props.data.filter(item => item.isAMatch === true)
```

Would return an array only with items that had a property isMatch that’s true